# I'm getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined' but my code still works

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first JavaScript project, it's a game I often play in the classroom with my students using analog methods(i.e. chalk and blackboard).

this is my js :

```js
// gets a random integer
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

//points of the game
const possibleValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, "T"];

// selects all the cells
const places = document.getElementsByClassName("place");

//assign random numbers to each cell
function assignValues() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= places.length; i++) {
    places[i].value = possibleValues[getRandomInt(0, 4)];
  }
}

assignValues();
console.log(places);
//shows the points when the cell is clicked
function showPoints() {
  event.target.style.fontSize = "xx-large";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

table {
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 800px;
  border: 10pc;
  border-color: black;
}

td input.place {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <!-- letters column -->
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

SO far my code seems to work but I'm getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined' in Chrome console, also console.log(places) is not working, but I remember it was working before.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: Or use `i < places.length` instead

Comment: I'd say that the script is loading before the DOM has constructed so therefore when the script hits the reference to places it does not exist YET. Move the code into an onload function so you can be sure things have loaded before it attempts to retrieve the elements.

Comment: @Elijah No it's not, OP says the code works, plus the script is included at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript Array's are 0 indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length), therefore you'll need to remove `1` from `array.length` if you're gonna loop through them with a for loop (`<=`), change

```
for (let i = 0; i <= places.length; i++) {
```

To:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= places.length - 1; i++) {
```

Or, use `i < places.length` so you only care if it's smaller then `i`

```js
// gets a random integer
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

//points of the game
const possibleValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, "T"];

// selects all the cells
const places = document.getElementsByClassName("place");

//assign random numbers to each cell
function assignValues() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= places.length - 1; i++) {
    places[i].value = possibleValues[getRandomInt(0, 4)];
  }
}

assignValues();
console.log(places);
//shows the points when the cell is clicked
function showPoints() {
  event.target.style.fontSize = "xx-large";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

table {
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 800px;
  border: 10pc;
  border-color: black;
}

td input.place {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <!-- letters column -->
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="place" type="button" value="" onclick="showPoints()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

should be < not <= in the for loop